# Developing an app for offline music - violate Apple’s policy?

Tags: ios, privacy

I recently felt motivated to start working on an app for offline music. I will be using YouTube API to let users search for songs and list suggestions, the option to play those songs and save them for offline listening.

However, I have noticed that most top-rated music apps in Apple Store do not offer offline listening. They are basically “YouTube” but with the ability to lock your screen and continue listening.

So I started wondering what is Apple’s view regarding music downloading for offline use? Do they remove and delete apps which offer this functionality?

I have only once downloaded an app from Apple  App Store which allowed me to save YouTube videos for offline view, and I have been using it since then. Although, it has been removed from Apple app store long ago.

In conclusion, if I develop an app which will store songs for offline use on users’ devices, will my app get rejected and removed from Apple App store? I know that if I just make it require internet and not store it on the device, my app will be just like every other music application there is on the app store.

Comment: If you don't own the music, which it looks like you don't, you can't allow offline storage of the music.  It's not Apple's rules, it's the owners of the music.  You've already seen that the most popular apps don't allow this and I think YouTube's ToS doesn't allow it either.

Comment: Please consider to check whether you are violating YouTube's terms of service. YouTube has already a similar service ongoing for a subscription fee. I don't think YouTube would be amused. BUT you may contribute your app e.g. via Cydia.